# How to know if the user block the messenger bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to know if the user blocks the chat bot. Going through the documentation I didn’t find a way to do it, so I had to create a work around. 
I send a message to the user and create a flag of sending; then I use the sleep function for 10 seconds. Every time a user receives a message my code change the flag from sending to send. After 10 seconds, if the flag is still on sending means that the receiver didn’t get the message, so I infer that the chat bot is blocked. 
There are some flaws with this work around like if the message takes more than 10 seconds to arrive and I don’t know why if I use the sleep function for >15 seconds, I get into a loop, and the Fb API start sending me requests.

Someone has a better solution??

I appreciate your help! (:

Comment: Have you checked for any permissions or other error codes in the API response? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/errors

Comment: You are right, now I am catching the error code from the API. Thanks!

Comment: what is the error code you are catching from blocked users?

Answer (score 1):

Check errors with code “10” subcode “2018108” or code “200” subcode “1545041”. These subcodes mostly define that user have blocked your bot/messenger conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I tested today, with the latest iOS Messenger app, and I found out, that, for each of the following cases

- User turns off messages
- User taps on 'somethings wrong' -> report -> other / spam / inappropriate (=this is what you probably mean by 'block')

the Facebook Messenger API returns

`{"error":{"message":"(#551) This person isn't available right now.","type":"OAuthException","code":551,"error_subcode":1545041,"fbtrace_id":"XXXXX"}}`

Thus, the answer to your question is to check for error code 551, subcode 1545041. Be aware that you will get back the 'blocked' users lumped together with those who tapped on 'turn off messages'.

By the way, you are able to see the percentage of users who blocked a Messsenger conversation by going to the associated Facebook Page and tapping on the top row at 'Insights'.

Hope this helps others, it took me a couple of hours of my life, to learn this :)